# modified java.policy ignored since installing fixpack 5 on Domino 8.5.3

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I'm using Apache fop in my Xpages Project. To get the code running from within SSJS i modified the the java.policy and added following lines to the grant section:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader"; 
permission java.util.logging.LoggingPermission "control";
```

After upgrading the 8.5.3 Domino Server to Fixpack 5 it seems that the modification are not working any more and i get AccessControlExceptions

```
java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.util.logging.LoggingPermission control)
java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
```

However if i add

```
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

everything works fine. 
Has someone an idea why the modifications are not working?

Comment: Were the permission lines still in the java.policy after the upgrade? I thought the java.policy got replaced by upgrades, but I'm not sure about point release upgrades. You may want to add a java.pol file instead. That will be used and will not get overwritten.

Comment: Great tip Paul! My experience is that every fixpack install will reset the java.policy file. Of course sometimes there might be updates needed by Domino.

Comment: The java.policy got replaced, but i added the lines again. 
But the java.pol is sill a good tip. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem now after upgrading from 9.0 to 9.0.1. Anyone found the root cause and/or fix for this? http://serverfault.com/questions/558931/granting-access-to-java-logger-with-java-policy-file-not-working-in-domino-9-0-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's a bug in 8.5.3 FP5 and 9.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/558931/granting-access-to-java-logger-with-java-policy-file-not-working-in-domino-9-0-1), SPR# RGAU9CSBWA, APAR LO77612. In your case the solution would be to upgrade to 9.0.

Comment: @LarsMigula The dates and descriptions are so close that I believe this SPR was opened by you.

Comment: I didn't open the SPR, but it's really very close to my description. Seems like someone opened it for my but didn't tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Paul is correct about the java.pol file (see http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/java-security-in-ibm-domino/). It survives updates to Domino. As far as I know java.policy is overwritten even by point-releases. I am pretty sure that I have been bitten by that anyway ;-)

/John